# Dynamic Aggregation Based on Row Value

Tags: date, dynamic, aggregate

I have a calendar table with a column [WeekFuzzy]. This column updates to show "CURRENT" for the current week and "PREVIOUS" for the previous week. There is also a [weekseq] column that is a running count of the week. I would like to make a column that counts backward from the current week to give us a static starting point where the current week is always zero.

I've tried joining in a filtered version of the table where [weekfuzzy]="CURRENT", but that just gives me the current weekseq and the rest of the rows are null.

```
SELECT
    cal.Week,
    cal.weekname,
    cal.weekfuzzy,
    cal.weekseq,
    CurCal.weekseq
FROM
    clientcalendar AS Cal
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT
      cal.week,
      cal.weekseq
  FROM
      clientcalendar AS Cal
  WHERE
      cal.weekfuzzy="CURRENT") AS CurCal ON cal.week=curcal.week
```